# Emacs face mode in local file variables

Tags: emacs, elisp

I tired to explicitly set a custom face for a file using local file variables:

```
# Local Variables:
# buffer-face-mode-face:'(:family "DejaVu Sans Mono")
# End:
```

Emacs catches up these variables, not showing, however, the file with the font that was required.

How can I write down the variables, so Emacs would show files with particular faces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I found a hint on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353246/how-do-i-set-an-emacs-buffer-name-with-a-file-local-variable), that's one of the possible solutions:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))
# eval: (buffer-face-mode t)
# End:
```

Or this trick:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq buffer-face-mode-face (face-font 'fixed-pitch))
# eval: (buffer-face-mode t)
# End:
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a *local variable list* work, don't forget that the `Local Variables` block has to be **appended at the end** of the file.
For emacs warnings about "*unsave variables*" as result of using `eval` when loading your file see
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html#Safe-File-Variables

Comment: Can you please post relevant information from link provided in you answer to avoid link rot